How to make realistic crumbs?
I am trying to make a realistic render of a chocolate donut with some raspberries in it; i am stuck in making those crumbs, i tried 2 different ways to get to my goal,the first one with geometry nodes (i don't really like it, it looks like some sort of virus) and the second one with particle system but with neither of these solution i am 100% happy, is there a better and effective way to do that (also i would like not have 500.000+ vertices as a result)?
Thanks

Possibly related: Powder In A Pile - you'd need to add some creative touch with maybe varying sized particles and maybe give the particles more geometry for large-scale concavities and a material with rough normal texture...

I think that your particle system solution looks pretty good, you can probably improve the material

I may be wrong, but are all crumbs made from fully detailed raspberry models, even the small ones? If so, then it's obvious why you have so many vertices.

I think the main problem with the first particle system is that the crumbs are too close together, and they are all the same color. In the photograph, you can see that there’s not only some space, but the smaller crumbs are wet and darker.

You can stack multiple layers of crumbs on top of each other to add more depth to it.

Here is how I did it in geometry nodes with a vertex group input. There are two layers of crumbs and a total of 100k vertices and 100k instances (I didn't realize the second layer of crumbs as it's not really needed)




This is definitely what i was looking for! My only problem with this process right now is that it shows me only the ico sphere, i don't know if the problem might be the realize instances node as it's the only thing different from your nodes: https://imgur.com/a/GhDNEw5

@Rama try to set the random value of the pick instance to integer, from 0 to 100 (in the instance on point group)
